# Music Artists On Tracks

Tags: music

I am trying to find the artists on songs for appropriate credit to those artists musicians vocalists. Is there a way to look up the complete music artists (such a vocal, dj, band) on songs?

Comment: I assume you're familiar with http://www.freedb.org/en/download__database.10.html but that it's insufficient for your needs?